# Turn off error for console.log on my eslint

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm trying to turn off lint warning for my eslint at VS code.

My code is contains.

```
console.log('blabla..');
```

eslint said as below.

```
 error  Unexpected console statement                      no-console
```

Even though already add no-restricted-syntax at my .eslintrc.json, no fixed.

Here is my .eslintrc.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "amd": true,
        "mocha": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "windows"
        ],
        "no-restricted-syntax": [
            "error",
            {
                "selector": "CallExpression[callee.object.name='console'][callee.property.name=/^(log|warn|error|info|trace)$/]",
                "message": "Unexpected property on console object was called"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What did I mistake?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Allowing the `console.log` to stay in code is requiring a separate rule. 
You need to add 'no-console' statement to your `eslint config rules`.

Like so:

```
rules: {
  "no-console": 0
}
```

A better practice is to warn you about all the `console.log` in your code, like so:

```
rules: {
  "no-console": 1
}
```

Comment: That is my wanted.   Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes you have to restart the development server.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice of Elad and went into the package.json to add the rule of "no-console": 0 and at first it didn't seem like it worked but this is because I needed to restart the development server. If it seems like it's not working, make sure you restart the development server because if you change anything in the package-json, you have to restart your server.

Answer (score -1):

You can add `// eslint-disable-line` if you need to ignore a specific (or multiple) line

Comment: This would disable all the rules on that particular line and hence should be avoided always. 
The OP just wanted to disable console and to achieve it at a particular line use 
`// eslint-disable-line no-console`